# Showing a code snippet in an HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, css, formatting

Like there is a code sample inserter in the stackoverflow's WYSIWYG text editor ([see image here](http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/8241/codesample.png))

I want such a formatter to show a code snippet in an html page with colored keywords and strings etc. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out google code prettify:  http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: This has always worked superbly for me (although it does rely on JavaScript if that is a concern to you).

Answer (score 1):

Check http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/
it's pretty popular and awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe? http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/syntax

Answer (score 0):

Geshi is quite awesome too: http://qbnz.com/highlighter/demo.php